# IONIC 3 compile error. Cannot build or run android emulator after adding file encryption plugin

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How to resolve this error. Is this ionic or android error. This error comes after install cordova file encryption plugin. before it run smoothly. Please any one know this error.

```
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[12:24:54]  build dev started ...
[12:24:55]  clean started ...
[12:24:55]  clean finished in 21 ms
[12:24:55]  copy started ...
[12:24:55]  deeplinks started ...
[12:24:55]  deeplinks finished in 208 ms
[12:24:55]  transpile started ...
[12:25:08]  transpile finished in 13.18 s
[12:25:08]  preprocess started ...
[12:25:08]  preprocess finished in 2 ms
[12:25:08]  webpack started ...
[12:25:14]  copy finished in 19.01 s
[12:25:26]  webpack finished in 17.95 s
[12:25:26]  sass started ...
[12:25:28]  sass finished in 1.99 s
[12:25:28]  postprocess started ...
[12:25:28]  postprocess finished in 25 ms
[12:25:28]  lint started ...
[12:25:28]  build dev finished in 34.05 s
> cordova build android
                              ^
G:\Android\****\platforms\android\src\com\disusered\Safe.java:120: error: cann
      CRYPTO = new Crypto(new SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain(CONTEXT), new SystemNati
                              ^
  symbol:   class SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain
  location: class Safe
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: G:\Android\***\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\file\AssetFiles
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove below plugin with

> ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat

and after that reinstall below  plugin by

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat

Comment: I resolve this. Actually error was the file encryption plugin. reinstalling plugin error was resolved. Thanks to share your idea

Comment: Hi, but the issue is still remaining after adding the cordova-safe plugin. Your solution is not resolve too.